# How to convert Seconds to HH:MM:SS using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, datetime

The situation is you have a value in Seconds (XXX.XX), and you want to convert to HH:MM:SS using T-SQL.

Example:

- 121.25 s becomes 00:02:01.25

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1267364.aspx

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You want to multiply out to milliseconds as the fractional part is discarded.

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, 121.25 * 1000, 0)
```

If you want it without the date portion you can use CONVERT, with style 114

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, 121.25 * 1000, 0), 114)
```

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, 121.25 * 1000, 0), 114) is it.

Comment: This won't work if you have more than 24 hours worth of seconds

Comment: Very neat. Use 108 if you don't want milliseconds, ie hh:mi:ss

Comment: If you have SQL 2008+ and just want the time portion; instead of converting to varchar:

SELECT CONVERT(time, DATEADD(ms, 121.25 * 1000, 0))

Comment: You can also do FORMAT(..., 'mm:ss')

Answer (score 61):

If your **time amount exceeds 24 hours** it won't be handled correctly with the DATEADD and CONVERT methods.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, 24*60*60 * 1000, 0), 114)
00:00:00:000
```

The following function will handle times exceeding 24 hours (~max 35,791,394 hours).

```
create function [dbo].[ConvertTimeToHHMMSS]
(
    @time decimal(28,3), 
    @unit varchar(20)
)
returns varchar(20)
as
begin

    declare @seconds decimal(18,3), @minutes int, @hours int;

    if(@unit = 'hour' or @unit = 'hh' )
        set @seconds = @time * 60 * 60;
    else if(@unit = 'minute' or @unit = 'mi' or @unit = 'n')
        set @seconds = @time * 60;
    else if(@unit = 'second' or @unit = 'ss' or @unit = 's')
        set @seconds = @time;
    else set @seconds = 0; -- unknown time units

    set @hours = convert(int, @seconds /60 / 60);
    set @minutes = convert(int, (@seconds / 60) - (@hours * 60 ));
    set @seconds = @seconds % 60;

    return 
        convert(varchar(9), convert(int, @hours)) + ':' +
        right('00' + convert(varchar(2), convert(int, @minutes)), 2) + ':' +
        right('00' + convert(varchar(6), @seconds), 6)

end
```

**Usage:**

```
select dbo.ConvertTimeToHHMMSS(123, 's')
select dbo.ConvertTimeToHHMMSS(96.999, 'mi')
select dbo.ConvertTimeToHHMMSS(35791394.999, 'hh')
0:02:03.000
1:36:59.940
35791394:59:56.400
```

Comment: Why the time longer then 24 hours will not be formatted correctly using DateAdd?

Comment: @gotqn: DateAdd() isn't the problem. Convert() is the problem. Convert() effectively wraps around to zero every 24 hours. If you use Convert() to format a 27-hour interval, it will return "03:00:00".

Comment: How to handle this formatting if the use case says results can be negative hh:mm:ss (eg. -340:23:34, 03:-4:05,13:54:-8 etc)

Comment: This is the way to go. None of the other solutions here will work properly for HHMMSS formatting beyond 24 hours. This will also help keep your queries neat.

Comment: Just be aware of the performance implications this function may have on larger datasets,  and test accordingly. Especially with it being non-inlined causing any dependent queries (at any level) to not be applicable for parallelization.

Answer (score 32):

For those having issues with using DATEADD and CONVERT for seconds exceeding 24 hours, we can use modulus to get around that:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, @seconds / 86400 ) + ':' + -- Days
CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, ( @seconds % 86400 ) * 1000, 0), 114)
as "Converted to D:HH:MM:SS.MS"
```

Answer (score 29):

```
DECLARE @seconds AS int = 896434;
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar, (@seconds / 86400))                --Days
    + ':' +
    CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ss, @seconds, 0), 108);    --Hours, Minutes, Seconds
```

Outputs:

```
10:09:00:34
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer -- it deals with `second`s, as the O.P. asked, avoids using an inefficient `scalar function`, and deals with multi-day spans appropriately.  The only minor nit I would add is that, in SQL Agent land, your elapsed-time/time-intervals for the "days" part typically use "days.hh:mm:ss", i.e. a `dot` instead of `colon`.  So for example `2.01:03:04` for 2 days, 1 hour, 3 minutes, 4 seconds.  Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

Using SQL Server 2008

```
declare @Seconds as int = 3600;
SELECT CONVERT(time(0), DATEADD(SECOND, @Seconds, 0)) as 'hh:mm:ss'
```

Comment: let me know the reason for downvoting.

Comment: Can't assign the result to a variable For example:

Answer (score 5):

Using SQL Server 05 I can get this to work by using:

```
declare @OrigValue int;
set @OrigValue = 121.25;
select replace(str(@OrigValue/3600,len(ltrim(@OrigValue/3600))+abs(sign(@OrigValue/359999)-1)) + ':' + str((@OrigValue/60)%60,2) + ':' + str(@OrigValue%60,2),' ','0')
```

Comment: this did not work for me. if you pass 896434 seconds - you want 10:09:00:34:000 and not 249:00:34

Answer (score 3):

Just in case this might be still interesting to anyone. The 'Format' Function can also be used, with SQL Server 2012+

> ```
> Declare @Seconds INT = 1000000;
> SELECT FORMAT(CAST(@Seconds/86400.000 AS datetime), 'HH:mm:ss');
> ```

OR

> ```
> Declare @Seconds INT = 1000000;
> SELECT CAST(FORMAT(CAST(@Seconds/86400.000 AS datetime), 'HH:mm:ss') AS TIME);
> ```

Comment: The FORMAT function is about 22 times slower than just about any other method you could come up with.

Comment: I'll take your word for it. Have never had queries where this impacted performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @TimeinSecond INT
SET @TimeinSecond = 340 -- Change the seconds
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((@TimeinSecond / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
```

Comment: this did not work for me. if you pass 896434 seconds - you want 10:09:00:34 and not 49:00:34

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT substring(convert (varchar(23),Dateadd(s,10000,LEFT(getdate(),11)),121),12,8)
```

10000 is your value in  sec

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use (typically for html table email reports)

```
declare @time int, @hms varchar(20)
set @time = 12345
set @hms = cast(cast((@Time)/3600 as int) as varchar(3)) 
  +':'+ right('0'+ cast(cast(((@Time)%3600)/60 as int) as varchar(2)),2) 
  +':'+ right('0'+ cast(((@Time)%3600)%60 as varchar(2)),2) +' (hh:mm:ss)'
select @hms
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Seconds INT = 86200;
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), 
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Seconds / 60 / 60 % 24)
+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Seconds / 60 % 60)
+':'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Seconds % 60) AS TIME), 100) AS [HH:MM:SS (AM/PM)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
set @duration= 112000
SELECT 
   "Time" = cast (@duration/3600 as varchar(3)) +'H'
         + Case 
       when ((@duration%3600 )/60)<10 then
                 '0'+ cast ((@duration%3600 )/60)as varchar(3))
       else 
               cast ((@duration/60) as varchar(3))
       End
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
cast(datediff(hh, '1900-01-01', dateadd(s, @Seconds), 0)) as varchar(10))
+ right(convert(char(8), dateadd(s, @Seconds), 0), 108),6) AS [Duration(H:MM:SS)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

To get a value with time datatype:

```
select convert(time(0),cast(0 as datetime)+3661*1e0/24/60/60)
```

To get a value with char datatype:

```
select convert(char,cast(0 as datetime)+3661*1e0/24/60/60,108)
```

- time(0) returns a time with minimal precision (hh:mm:s)
- cast(0 as datetime) returns 1900-01-01 ...
- 3661 is **your number in seconds**= 1 hour 1 minute 1 second
- 1e0 prevent truncations (it's the number 1 expanded with decimal)
- datetime+1= tomorrow, and datetime+1e0/24/60/60= 1 second
- or replace that, with .../24/3600 (one less calculation)

Output:

```
01:01:01
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
CAST((Duration)/60 AS NVARCHAR(9)) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(Duration % 60 AS NVARCHAR(9)), 2)
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers. (BTW, the answer isn't correct)