# Simple TSQL clause not working

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to do exactly what [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262497/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-using-t-sql) does, but it is not working and have no idea why.

My version is the following:

```
select convert(varchar, dateadd(ss, @tracker, 0), 114)
```

where `@tracker` is just an `INT` variable that holds a certain number of seconds.

The error I get is: `Function DATEADD invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).`

Appreciate any help.

I am using Sybase.

Comment: are you getting an error? how is it not working?

Comment: In what way is it not working?  Do you get an error? Do you have more than 24 hours worth of seconds in `@tracker`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, according to [this documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks136.htm), you should use `ss`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(ss, @tracker, "00:00:00"), 114)
```

Comment: The error is: `Function DATEADD invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).`

Comment: Hey guys, tried all the suggestions, still not getting it, for testing my code is as simple as: `declare @tracker INT
set @tracker = 1000
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(second, 0, @tracker), 114)`

Comment: I guess 0 isn't recognized as a date, try "0/0/0000"