# T-SQL Format seconds as HH:MM:SS time

Tags: sql, t-sql, time, format, seconds

Is there any tricky way to format seconds like hours:minutes:seconds. For example,

> 3660

seconds will be displayed as

> 01h 01m 00s

or

> 01:01:00

I am aware of the standard way of doing this:

1. Divide all seconds on 3600 to get the hours
2. Divide the rest seconds on 60 to get the minutes
3. The rest are the seconds

I met the following issues:

1. I am not able to create separate function that do this.
2. My code is in view using several CTEs. So, variables can be declare
   using the CTEs only.
3. I am not able to use the standard solution because I will have
   results  bigger then one day - [How to convert Seconds to HH:MM:SS using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262497/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-using-t-sql)

Comment: So if you have 86399 seconds, you want 23:59:59, but if you have 86400 seconds, you want 24:00:00, etc.?

Comment: If I have 3 days in seconds it will shows 72:00:00. I get your point, I should have said that there is no max value for hours.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT Seconds, 
    RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Seconds/3600),2)  
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(Seconds%3600)/60),2) 
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Seconds%60),2) AS [HH:MM:SS] 
FROM table1
```

Result:

| Seconds | HH:MM:SS |
| --- | --- |
| 3660 | 01:01:00 |
| 3800 | 01:03:20 |
| 4200 | 01:10:00 |
| 600 | 00:10:00 |
| 60 | 00:01:00 |
| 86400 | 24:00:00 |
| 86800 | 24:06:40 |

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1ee95a/1)

---

#### Update

The above query works fine if the total number of hours are less than 100 i.e. (99:59:59). If you need more than that you can use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Seconds,
    CASE Seconds/3600 
    WHEN 0 THEN RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Seconds/3600),2) 
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Seconds/3600) END
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),(Seconds%3600)/60),2) 
    +':' 
    + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),Seconds%60),2) AS [HH:MM:SS]
FROM table1
```

Result:

| Seconds | HH:MM:SS |
| --- | --- |
| 3660 | 1:01:00 |
| 3800 | 1:03:20 |
| 4200 | 1:10:00 |
| 600 | 00:10:00 |
| 60 | 00:01:00 |
| 9999930 | 2777:45:30 |
| 359999 | 99:59:59 |
| 360000 | 100:00:00 |
| 86800 | 24:06:40 |

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/01cd4/1)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(SS,***seconds***,0),108) as 'FieldName'
```

will return `HH:MM:SS`

Example:

> 46800 seconds = 1:00 PM
>
> FieldName = 13:00:00

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this should be the preferred solution if to convert a column on an entire table of records.

Comment: Note that the TIME datatype does not support values greater than 86,399, so this does not work for the original intent where times may reflect more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT cast(seconds/3600 as varchar(6)) +
right(cast(dateadd(second, seconds,0) as time(0)), 6)
FROM <yourtable>
```