# SQL Server - calculate elapsed time between two datetime stamps in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, elapsedtime

I have a SQL Server table that has a "Time" column.  The table is a log table the houses status messages and timestamps for each message.  The log table is inserted into via a batch file. There is an ID column that groups rows together.  Each time the batch file runs it initializes the ID and writes records.  What I need to do is get the elapsed time from the first record in an ID set to the last record of the same ID set.  I started toying with select Max(Time) - Min(Time) from logTable where id =  but couldn't figure out how to format it correctly.  I need it in HH:MM:SS.

Comment: Please let us know the datatype of the "Time" column.  DateTime, DateTime2, Time, Timestamp, etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support the SQL standard interval data type. Your best bet is to calculate the difference in seconds, and use a function to format the result. The native function CONVERT() might appear to work fine *as long as your interval is less than 24 hours*. But CONVERT() isn't a good solution for this.

```
create table test (
  id integer not null,
  ts datetime not null
  );

insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:00');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 09:00');
insert into test values (1, '2012-01-01 08:30');
insert into test values (2, '2012-01-01 08:30');
insert into test values (2, '2012-01-01 10:30');
insert into test values (2, '2012-01-01 09:00');
insert into test values (3, '2012-01-01 09:00');
insert into test values (3, '2012-01-02 12:00');
```

Values were chosen in such a way that for

- id = 1, elapsed time is 1 hour
- id = 2, elapsed time is 2 hours, and
- id = 3, elapsed time is 3 hours.

This SELECT statement includes one column that calculates seconds, and one that uses CONVERT() with subtraction.

```
select t.id,
       min(ts) start_time,
       max(ts) end_time,
       datediff(second, min(ts),max(ts)) elapsed_sec,
       convert(varchar, max(ts) - min(ts), 108) do_not_use
from test t
group by t.id;

ID  START_TIME                 END_TIME                   ELAPSED_SEC  DO_NOT_USE
1   January, 01 2012 08:00:00  January, 01 2012 09:00:00  3600         01:00:00
2   January, 01 2012 08:30:00  January, 01 2012 10:30:00  7200         02:00:00
3   January, 01 2012 09:00:00  January, 02 2012 12:00:00  97200        03:00:00
```

Note the misleading "03:00:00" for the 27-hour difference on id number 3.

[Function to format elapsed time in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11191244/562459)

Comment: @Catcall....question: your query worked for these two dates which spanned over two days  (2012-12-13 15:10:12.050 and 2012-12-12 20:16:47.160).  Your results were 68005 seconds and 18:53:24.  This appears right.  Not sure why do_not_use 18:53:24 is there?

Comment: CONVERT() returns the wrong answer for intervals over 24 hours. The difference between your two timestamps is less than 24 hours. The column "do_not_use" is meant to discourage you from using CONVERT() to format intervals.

Comment: @Catcall...yep, I understood the meaning of the "do_not_use" column. I was curious about CONVERT()....and your explanation is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: what does 108 in the convert query stand for?

Comment: @tiqa: 108 is a [*style* argument to CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). ("hh:mi:ss")

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATED:**

Correctly calculate a timespan in SQL Server, **even if more than 24 hours**:

```
-- Setup test data
declare @minDate datetime = '2012-12-12 20:16:47.160'
declare @maxDate datetime = '2012-12-13 15:10:12.050'

-- Get timespan in hh:mi:ss
select cast(
        (cast(cast(@maxDate as float) - cast(@minDate as float) as int) * 24) /* hours over 24 */
        + datepart(hh, @maxDate - @minDate) /* hours */
        as varchar(10))
    + ':' + right('0' + cast(datepart(mi, @maxDate - @minDate) as varchar(2)), 2) /* minutes */
    + ':' + right('0' + cast(datepart(ss, @maxDate - @minDate) as varchar(2)), 2) /* seconds */

-- Returns 18:53:24
```

Edge cases that show inaccuracy are especially welcome!

Comment: @Tim....this almost works.  For these two dates (2012-12-13 15:10:12.050 and  2012-12-12 20:16:47.160) your query returned a result of 19:54:25 when the actual value is 18:53:24.  Ideas?

Comment: @MikeTWebb you might find the current version to work well if you don't want to use a function or be limited in how many hours can be represented.

Answer (score 14):

```
DECLARE @EndTime AS DATETIME, @StartTime AS DATETIME

SELECT @StartTime = '2013-03-08 08:00:00', @EndTime = '2013-03-08 08:30:00'

SELECT CAST(@EndTime - @StartTime AS TIME)
```

Result: `00:30:00.0000000`

Format result as you see fit.

Comment: This only works in SQL Server 2008+, but it's a great solution presuming you can guarantee the version.

Comment: Will fail if time is greater than 24 hours

Answer (score 2):

The best and simple way:

```
Convert(varchar, {EndTime} - {StartTime}, 108)
```

Just like Anri noted.

Comment: Yes and no.  This will not work for time spans over 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Use the DATEDIFF to return value in milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, ...

DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)

**interval** *REQUIRED* - The time/date part to return. Can be one of the following values:

```
year, yyyy, yy = Year
quarter, qq, q = Quarter
month, mm, m = month
dayofyear = Day of the year
day, dy, y = Day
week, ww, wk = Week
weekday, dw, w = Weekday
hour, hh = hour
minute, mi, n = Minute
second, ss, s = Second
millisecond, ms = Millisecond
```

**date1, date2** *REQUIRED* - The two dates to calculate the difference between

Answer (score 1):

`select convert(varchar, Max(Time) - Min(Time) , 108) from logTable where id=...`

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps. I can set variables for Elapsed Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds.
You can format this to your liking or include in a user defined function.

Note: Don't use DateDiff(hh,@Date1,@Date2).  It is not reliable!  It rounds in unpredictable ways

Given two dates...
(Sample Dates: two days, three hours, 10 minutes, 30 seconds difference)

```
declare @Date1 datetime = '2013-03-08 08:00:00'
declare @Date2 datetime = '2013-03-10 11:10:30'
declare @Days decimal
declare @Hours decimal
declare @Minutes decimal
declare @Seconds decimal

select @Days = DATEDIFF(ss,@Date1,@Date2)/60/60/24 --Days
declare @RemainderDate as datetime = @Date2 - @Days
select @Hours = datediff(ss, @Date1, @RemainderDate)/60/60 --Hours
set @RemainderDate = @RemainderDate - (@Hours/24.0)
select @Minutes = datediff(ss, @Date1, @RemainderDate)/60 --Minutes
set @RemainderDate = @RemainderDate - (@Minutes/24.0/60)
select @Seconds = DATEDIFF(SS, @Date1, @RemainderDate)    
select @Days as ElapsedDays, @Hours as ElapsedHours, @Minutes as ElapsedMinutes, @Seconds as ElapsedSeconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you in getting the exact time between two time stamps

```
Create PROC TimeDurationbetween2times(@iTime as time,@oTime as time) 
As  
Begin  

DECLARE @Dh int, @Dm int, @Ds int ,@Im int, @Om int, @Is int,@Os int     

SET @Im=DATEPART(MI,@iTime)  
SET @Om=DATEPART(MI,@oTime)  
SET @Is=DATEPART(SS,@iTime)  
SET @Os=DATEPART(SS,@oTime)  

SET @Dh=DATEDIFF(hh,@iTime,@oTime)  
SET @Dm = DATEDIFF(mi,@iTime,@oTime)  
SET @Ds = DATEDIFF(ss,@iTime,@oTime)  

DECLARE @HH as int, @MI as int, @SS as int  

if(@Im>@Om)  
begin  
SET @Dh=@Dh-1  
end  
if(@Is>@Os)  
begin  
SET @Dm=@Dm-1  
end  

SET @HH = @Dh  
SET @MI = @Dm-(60*@HH)  
SET @SS = @Ds-(60*@Dm)  

DECLARE @hrsWkd as varchar(8)         

SET @hrsWkd = cast(@HH as char(2))+':'+cast(@MI as char(2))+':'+cast(@SS as char(2))          

select @hrsWkd as TimeDuration   

End
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @StartDate DateTime,@EndDate Datetime,
@seconds int,@secondsb int,
@minutes int, @minutesB int,
@Hours int,@hoursB int,
@Days int, @Daysb int,
@Years int;

set @StartDate='2021-01-10 10:12:13.987'
set @EndDate=getdate() --You can enter end date in above similar manners or use getdate() to compare current date and time
    
set @Seconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate)
set @secondsb=@Seconds%60
set @Minutes=(@Seconds-@SecondsB)/60
set @MinutesB=@Minutes%60
set @Hours=(@Minutes-@MinutesB)/60
set @HoursB=@Hours%24
set @days=(@Hours-@HoursB)/24
set @DaysB=@Days%365
set @Years=(@Days-@DaysB)/365

Select @Years Years, @Daysb Days, @hoursB Hours,@minutesB Minutes, @secondsb Seconds
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).