# SQL date format [h]:mm:ss like Excel does, beyond 24 hr

Tags: sql, t-sql, format, sql-date-functions

There is a translation for Excel built-in date **format** [h]:`mm:ss` in T-SQL or any SQL platform?

example:

```
    General [h]:mm:ss   [mm]:ss     [ss]
   1.00000  24:00:00    1440:00         86400
   1.00000  24:00:00    1440:00         86400
```

SUM

```
   2.00000  48:00:00    2880:00         172800
```

For T-SQL I will select

```
Without century (yy) (1)    With century (yyyy) Standard    Input/Output (3)
  14                             114                   -    hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)
```

Or by default 108, I am discerning is do I have to recreate a function that can do the 
`hh:mi:ss:mmm`(**+24h**)?

Comments are very welcome;

Answer (score 3):

While SQL Server's `time` datatype is supposed to [map to the CLR's timespan datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx), it only supports intervals less than 24 hours.

SQL Server's [`datediff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) is also tricky when it comes to calculating an interval as it calculates the *datepart boundaries crossed* between two datetimes.  For example, this should be an interval of 1 second, but datediff will tell you it's an hour if you ask for hours:

```
select datediff(hh, '2013-01-01T23:59:59', '2013-01-02T00:00:00')
-- Returns 1
```

As such, you might have to roll your own function when it comes to this, though hopefully  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867469/880904) might get you started:

```
-- Setup test data
declare @minDate datetime = '2012-12-12 20:16:47.160'
declare @maxDate datetime = '2012-12-17 15:10:12.050'

-- Get timespan in hh:mi:ss
select cast(
        (cast(cast(@maxDate as float) - cast(@minDate as float) as int) * 24) /* hours over 24 */
        + datepart(hh, @maxDate - @minDate) /* hours */
        as varchar(10))
    + ':' + right('0' + cast(datepart(mi, @maxDate - @minDate) as varchar(2)), 2) /* minutes */
    + ':' + right('0' + cast(datepart(ss, @maxDate - @minDate) as varchar(2)), 2) /* seconds */

-- Returns 114:53:24
```

Comment: Will try this, talking with my partner to see how ti implement it because we already have data in decimals but yes indeed a good start!

Comment: I would never have thought that the T-SQL `time` was supposed to map to a timespan type on the client side. I'd always considered it a point in time, just like `datetime` or `datetime2` but without the date part. Thanks for that link, which opened (or rather *widened*) my eyes.