# How to convert seconds into hh:mm format in Power Bi?

Tags: date, datetime, powerbi, dax

In Power Bi, I have a table that contains `Name` and `TimeSpent` by user in seconds.
I want to convert total seconds spent by all users into duration format `(hh:mm)`

When I am getting seconds in hh:mm format for each user from database query, the values are coming up like these `12:63` etc. After importing these values into power bi, I tried to set its datatype to `DateTime` format but power bi shows an error saying that it is not a valid value. If I set the datatype of the column as `string` then strings dont add up.

What can be the ideal way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262497/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-using-t-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following DAX:

```
HHMMSS = 
INT(Table[TimeSpent] / 3600) & ":" &
RIGHT("0" & INT((Table[TimeSpent] - INT(Table[TimeSpent] / 3600) * 3600) / 60), 2) & ":" &
RIGHT("0" & MOD(Table[TimeSpent], 3600), 2)
```

[Source](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/formatting-time-value-to-hh-mm-ss/td-p/85249)

Comment: suppose my total seconds are 1625038 which are `151 hours` and `23 minutes`. Using this formula, the hours are coming `51:23`, `1` is getting truncated.

Comment: @Sonali I have updated the DAX. Please check if it works.

Comment: Hi @Sonali Does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.

Comment: I changed it a little `IF(INT(Query1[Total Time] / 3600) = 0,"00",INT(Query1[Total Time] / 3600)) & ":" &
RIGHT("0" & INT((Query1[Total Time] - INT(Query1[Total Time] / 3600) * 3600) / 60), 2)`

Comment: can anyone help in adding datepart as well in above query!

Answer (score 9):

you can solve this in one line:

```
measure = FORMAT(TIME(0, 0, tableNAME[your_column]), "HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: For this to work on a new calculated column, you need to replace ; with ,

Comment: if you only want minutes and seconds its "nn:ss"

Answer (score 2):

DAX code:

```
 = TIME(0,0,SUM('Table'[Timespent]))
```

Then click the modelling tab and choose Format - Date Time and choose the appropriate format.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar question but for D:HH:MM:SS, code below if it's of use.

```
DurTime (meas) = 
VAR vDur = <<<duration in CALCULATE(SUM(seconds)) >>>
  RETURN INT(vDur/86400) & ":" &                     //Days
    RIGHT("0" & INT(MOD(vDur/3600,24)),2) & ":" &    //Hours 
    RIGHT("0" & INT(MOD(vDur/60,60)),2) & ":" &      //Minutes
    RIGHT("0" & INT(MOD(vDur,60)),2)                 //Seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a better formula, which I'm using in PBI:
`HHMMSS = FORMAT(TIME(int(Table[TimeSpent] / 3600); int(mod(Table[TimeSpent]; 3600) / 60);int(mod(mod(Table[TimeSpent]; 3600); 60))); "HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a Power BI Measure wich is easy to read for this problem, code below if it's of use.

```
HH:MM = 
VAR TotalDuration = SUM(tableNAME[your_column] ) //if you use a measure just leave the SUM part out
VAR TotalHours = TRUNC (TotalDuration/3600)
VAR Min_ =  FORMAT(TRUNC(TotalDuration - TotalHours * 3600),"00")
RETURN
    TotalHours & ":" & Min_
```

The solution is adopted from the top answer of this question  [PowerBi Duration calculation in hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388603/powerbi-duration-calculation-in-hhmmss)

Answer (score 0):

```
ROUNDDOWN(TableName[ColumnName]/3600,0)&":"&ROUNDDOWN(TableName[ColumnName]/60,0)-ROUNDDOWN(TableName[ColumnName]/3600,0)*60&":"&TableName[ColumnName]-ROUNDDOWN(TableName[ColumnName]/3600,0)*3600-(ROUNDDOWN(TableName[ColumnName]/60,0)-ROUNDDOWN(TableName[ColumnName]/3600,0)*60)*60
```

Comment: This will give appropriate result, test it.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved a template for this:

**This will enable to convert seconds into `D:HH:MM:SS` format**

```
D:HH:MM:SS = 

VAR D = int([AVG CBT]/86400)

VAR A_D = [AVG CBT]- D * 86400

VAR HH = RIGHT(0 & INT(A_D/3600),2)

VAR A_HH = A_D - HH * 3600

VAR  MM = RIGHT(0 & INT(A_HH/60),2)

VAR A_MM = A_HH - MM*60

VAR SS = RIGHT(0 & INT(A_MM),2)

RETURN
D & ":" & HH & ":" & MM & ":" & SS
```

I think it will resolve most needs.

Kishan.

Comment: While pointless to begin with (see Jonas Correa's answer), I find timo's 2018 rendition more readable.