# Duration calculation in hh:mm:ss using Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have the following DAX in Power BI to calculate duration. How can I include the seconds?

```
Total Duration = sumx('Sheet1'; hour('Sheet1'[Duration])) +
TRUNC(sumx('Sheet1'; MINUTE('Sheet1'[Duration]))/60) & ":" &
mod(sumx('Sheet1'; MINUTE('Sheet1'[Duration])); 60)& ":00"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
= FORMAT(SUM('Sheet1'[Duration]), "hh:mm:ss")
```

If the duration can cover more than 24 hours, then you may need to handle days separately. Something like this:

```
Format Duration (d.hh:mm:ss) =
VAR TotalDuration = SUM ( 'Sheet1'[Duration] )
VAR TotalDays = TRUNC ( TotalDuration )
VAR HrMinSec = FORMAT ( TotalDuration - TotalDays, "hh:mm:ss" )
RETURN
    TotalDays & "." & HrMinSec
```

To keep everything in hours:

```
Format Duration =
VAR TotalDuration = SUM ( 'Sheet1'[Duration] )
VAR TotalHours = TRUNC ( 24 * TotalDuration )
VAR MinSec = FORMAT ( TotalDuration - TotalHours / 24, "nn:ss" )
RETURN
    TotalHours & ":" & MinSec
```

Comment: This will fail if duration (and OP specifically said *duration*) exceeds 24 hours.

Comment: One could add `if (TotalHours < 10, "0" & TotalHours, TotalHours) & ":" ...` in case you need the leading `0`, ie. `01:30`.

Comment: I'd recommend `FORMAT ( TotalHours, "00" )` instead of the `IF` you suggested for left padding.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in seconds you can use:

```
=FORMAT((DATAINSECONDS/3600)/24; "HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=FORMAT((DATAINSECONDS/3600)/24; "HH:mm:ss")
```

This solution works with time, but it doesn't work with duration. If your duration less than 24 hours, time and duration are the same, and the solution works. But if your duration exceeds 24 hours this solution doesn't work. For example, try it for 87000 seconds.

A better solution in Power BI is to transform to duration in a power query.

Answer (score -1):

```
Total_ = sumx('dados'; hour('dados'[Duration])) + TRUNC(sumx('dados';
         MINUTE('dados'[Duration]))/60) & ":" & mod(sumx('dados'; 
         MINUTE('dados'[Duration])); 60) + 
         TRUNC(SUMX('dados';SECOND('dados'[Duração]))/60) & ":" & 
         mod(sumx('dados'; SECOND('dados'[Duration])); 60)
```

Comment: try to enclose your code part of the solution  within backtick quotes. See the formatting help page of stackoverflow  : https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.