# Converting date difference to time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

```
@Start_Date datetime
@End_Date  datetime

@End_Date - @Start_Date = 5 days, 3 hours, 2 min, 10 sec
```

How to convert it to hours:minutes:seconds?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's an answer from 2009: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262497/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-using-t-sql You might also be able to use the `FORMAT` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Seconds to HH:MM:SS using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262497/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-using-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Thousands of ways to do this, but this is a simple one.

Assume your dates are @d1 and @d2, this will work:

```
select convert(varchar,floor(convert(float,@d1-@d2))*24)
   +':'+convert(varchar,datepart(minute,@d1-@d2))
   +':'+convert(varchar,datepart(second,@d1-@d2))
```