# Converting Time To Different Format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm requiring assistance in converting seconds to a more readable format and hence needing help converting it.

For example, if my columns are giving the following output (in seconds):

```
                         156
                         253
                          20
                          85
                          95
                         252
```

I need to turn this into something like this:

```
                        02:36
                        04:13
                        00:20
                        01:25
                        01:35
                        04:12
```

My Query producing this output:

```sql
datediff([second], (Select TOP 1 [ActualStart] 
                   from Runtime_CTE 
                   where HelperObjectID = [Report ID] ORDER BY ActualStart DESC), 
          [Previous Run]) as [Run Time]
```

Could someone help me out in updating my query?

Thanks.

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Whoops, fixed.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(ms, 156*1000, 0), 114)

Comment: @ErayBalkanli why *varchar*? The OP is asking for a time value, not text

Comment: Don't you need HH at all? always smaller than 1 hour values you will use?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, op says: "'m requiring assistance in converting seconds to a more readable format"

Comment: @ErayBalkanli that's `time`.

Comment: Be careful -- this is a *duration*, not a *time*. Approaches involving conversion to `TIME` will fail if the duration is more than 24 hours.

Comment: I think you only need to change `[second]` to `[minute]`

Comment: @LifeOfJona you can probably get rid of the subquery by using the `FIRST_VALUE` windowing function.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli the query you used probably came [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262497/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-using-t-sql) and deals with *milliseconds*. How to display a decimal, date or time is up to the client application too, not the type itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the value to the time midnight:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, YourColumn, CONVERT(time(0), '00:00')) AS TimeValue
FROM YourTable...
```

For example, the value `156` returns `00:02:36`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 156,CONVERT(time(0), '00:00'));
```

Comment: Hi Larnu, is there a way to eliminate miliseconds here?

Comment: Worth mentioning that it will only work for values less than 86400 (number of seconds in a day)

Comment: @Larnu, when I run your query in SSMS2017, my result is: 00:02:36.0000000, I wonder if I can get rid of .0000000 without using varchar?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli are you using `time(7)` instead of `time(0)`? I can't replicate the behaviour in SQL Server 2012 - 2017.

Comment: @Larnu, ah OK, I was using like convert(time,'00:00'), you added (0) later i believe, thank you! upvoted

Comment: I had `time(0)` in the top answer the whole time; I had omitted the `(0)` in the latter example in error.

Comment: @Larnu You can use just `SELECT DATEADD(s, 156, 0)`

Comment: @Larnu Hi Larnu, thanks for your answer but however, I still need to use the datediff   because I'd like to know the difference from the starting and ending time duration. How would I also add that in here? 

thanks.

Comment: What starting or ending time @LifeOfJona? YOu only have one column.

Comment: @Larnu The query that I posted produces just one of my columns and I need the datediff in there in order to produce it. How can I implement your query in my then?

Comment: Without the full query, I can't answer your question, @LifeOfJona . I can only answer with the information I have and the question you ask. There's no `CASE` expression in your query, so i can't tell you how it should appear in the `THEN`, but you should easily be able to implement the above into any expression. if you don't understand what the above does, you should be asking about that, so you *can* implement it.

Comment: As you've only asked how to convert a value like `156` into a time, that's what this answer does. Perhaps you need to ask a new question, with your next requirement. Like i said, there's nothing in what you ask on how to implement the logic into a `DATEDIFF` or use in a `CASE` expression.