# Look up in same table with different value reference sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, lookup

I'd like some help with a code. I have TableA where Btime is sometimes 0.

```
  TableA

       ID    Dest   Orig    Bcode   Btime
       FB8E  GD     TR      KL      3600
       AC2A  BO     VR      KS      2700
       65B3  GD     AE      LH      7800
       AF85  NY     BU      NWG     3300
       B32A  BO     VR      KS      0
       B42L  NY     BU      NWG     0
       F66D  BO     VR      KS      2700
       N20S  NY     BU      NWG     3300
```

I need to get from the same table the value of Btime where Dest, Orig and Bcode are the same as in the row where Btime is 0 and convert Btime to HH:MM:SS

The result would be:

```
      ID    Dest    Orig    Bcode   Btime
      FB8E  GD      TR      KL      01:00:00
      AC2A  BO      VR      KS      00:45:00
      65B3  GD      AE      LH      02:10:00
      AF85  NY      BU      NWG     00:55:00
      B32A  BO      VR      KS      00:45:00
      B42L  NY      BU      NWG     00:55:00
```

How can I get this for my entire table if there are multiple values that can meet this condition?

Version is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)

Comment: What if there are multiple records with Btime that fits this condition?

Comment: There is no SQL Server 15.0.18142; the latest version of SQL Server 15 (SQL Server 2019 Preview) is 15.0.1900.25. Tell us your version of SQL Server, not your SSMS build version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server convert seconds to dd hh mm ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262497/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-using-t-sql).

Comment: Yes that is true, there are multiple records wiht Btime that fits this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the values to a `time` for the format and use window functions to fill in the value:

```
select t.*,
       dateadd(second, new_btime, convert(time, 0)) as new_btime_formatted
from (select t.*,
             (case when btime = 0
                   then max(btime) over (partition by dest, orig, bcode)
                   else btime
              end) as new_btime
      from t
     ) t;
```