# How to take table data hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, average

I'm using following SQL query to take AvgTime, when pass two dates to `fnDatetoSeconds` its return time difference in seconds. in above query return output in minutes.

I need take it as `HH.MM.SS` . how can I do it

```
SELECT
ISNULL(CAST(AVG(CASE WHEN (l.Status = 5 OR l.Status = 6) THEN dbo.fnDatetoSeconds(l.AssistedTime, l.AddedTime, NULL)*1.0 ELSE NULL END)/60.00 AS DECIMAL(18,6)), 0) AS AvgTime
ISNULL(CAST(AVG(CASE WHEN (l.Status = 2) THEN dbo.fnDatetoSeconds(l.CompletedTime, l.AddedTime, NULL)*1.0 ELSE NULL END)/60.00 AS DECIMAL(18,6)), 0) AS AvgTimeNew

FROM @LobbyRecords l;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Seconds to HH:MM:SS using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262497/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-using-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

This addresses the original question.

If you have two times and you want the average as a time, I would recommend:

```
select convert(time,
               dateadd(second,
                       avg( datediff(second, l.AddedTime, l.AssistedTime)),
                       0
                      )
              )
from @LobbyRecords l
where l.status in (5, 6);
```

I moved the `case` condition to a `where` clause just to simplify the logic to focus on key idea -- add the average number of seconds to `0`.

Comment: Sir, I need case statement, because I have separate columns inside that select statement, each one need separate case logic, so I can't use it inside where clause. so please give me an answer with case statement.

Comment: please check my updated question, so you can take idea,what I'm saying. there have separate columns like that

Comment: please help me sir